# JavaScript add-in for Word 2016 (MSO) does not appear in top toolbar

Tags: office-js, word-addins

We developed a Word add-in using the Word JavaScript API, and any users who use the volume license of Word 2016 MSO (16.0.4939.1000) on Windows 10 cannot see the add-in in the top toolbar.

The users can install the add-in from AppSource and launch it. However, the add-in is supposed to appear in its own custom tab, but it doesn't. The user has to re-add the plugin from the "My add-ins" menu every time they launch Word.

Below are what I believe to be the relevant parts of the `manifest.xml` file:

```
<Requirements>
    <Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.1">
        <Set Name="WordApi" MinVersion="1.1" />
    </Sets>
</Requirements>
```

```
<CustomTab id="TabXX">
    <Group id="XX.Group1">
        <Label resid="XX.Group1Label" />
        <Icon>
            <!-- Images removed for simplicity -->
        </Icon>
        <Control xsi:type="Button" id="XX.TaskpaneButton">
            <Label resid="XX.TaskpaneButton.Label" />
            <Supertip>
                <Title resid="XX.TaskpaneButton.Label" />
                <Description resid="XX.TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" />
            </Supertip>
            <Icon>
                <!-- Images removed for simplicity -->
            </Icon>
            <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                <TaskpaneId>XXPanel</TaskpaneId>
                <SourceLocation resid="XX.Taskpane.Url" />
            </Action>
        </Control>
        <Control xsi:type="Button" id="XX.SignOutButton">
            <Label resid="XX.SignOutButton.Label" />
            <Supertip>
                <Title resid="XX.SignOutButton.Label" />
                <Description resid="XX.SignOutButton.Tooltip" />
            </Supertip>
            <Icon>
                <!-- Images removed for simplicity -->
            </Icon>
            <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                <FunctionName>logout</FunctionName>
            </Action>
        </Control>
    </Group>
    <Label resid="XX.CustomTab.Label" />
</CustomTab>
```

```
    <Resources>
      <bt:Images>
        <!-- Images removed for simplicity -->
      </bt:Images>
      <bt:Urls>
        <bt:Url id="XX.Taskpane.Url" DefaultValue="https://wordapp.xx.com/index.html?v=1.0.0.0" />
        <bt:Url id="XX.SignOutButton.Url" DefaultValue="https://wordapp.xx.com/#/app/logout" />
        <bt:Url id="XX.GetStarted.LearnMoreUrl" DefaultValue="https://www.xx.com/" />
        <bt:Url id="XX.FunctionFile.Url" DefaultValue="https://wordapp.xx.com/function-file/function-file.html" />
      </bt:Urls>
      <bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:String id="XX.TaskpaneButton.Label" DefaultValue="XX" />
        <bt:String id="XX.Group1Label" DefaultValue="ThoughtRiver" />
        <bt:String id="XX.CustomTab.Label" DefaultValue="XX" />
        <bt:String id="XX.GetStarted.Title" DefaultValue="Get started with XX!" />
        <bt:String id="XX.SignOutButton.Label" DefaultValue="Sign out" />
      </bt:ShortStrings>
      <bt:LongStrings>
        <bt:String id="XX.TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Click to load the add-in" />
        <bt:String id="XX.GetStarted.Description" DefaultValue="The add-in was loaded successfully. Go to the XX tab and click the 'Show Taskpane' button to get started." />
        <bt:String id="XX.SignOutButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Click to Sign Out" />
      </bt:LongStrings>
    </Resources>
```

Is there anything wrong with the above configuration?

Are custom tabs supported for add-ins from the AppSource store in the volume license of Word 2016 (I know they are supported for COM add-ins)?

Is adding the add-in to an existing tab supported?

Thanks in advance,

Morgan

Comment: could you please share the name of this add-in? we may have a try to see what the problem is

Comment: @RaymondLu Sure, the add-in is ThoughtRiver Contract Pre-screening:
https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/office/WA200000668?src=office&tab=Overview

Comment: It works in my side, it has a new tab showing as ThoughtRiver, i am on windows 10, word  version 2004 (build 12730)

Comment: @RaymondLu The problem occurs in the volume license (MSO) version of Word, on the latest build (~16.0.4939.1000) and all builds before it. Are you able to test the add-in on that or a similar build?

The add-in works fine on Office 365, Mac, etc.

I'm not sure which version of Word build 12730 is for.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? Have the same issue (Office 2016 Volume).  It shows up in "Insert > My Add-Ins" though.

Answer (score 0):

Add-in command is not support in word 2016.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/add-in-commands-requirement-sets

You can use isSetSupport to check Add-in commands requirement sets. if it's not supported, Creating related button on taskpane as a workaround

Comment: Thank you for the response. Can you provide a bit more information about the workaround? Is there documentation for creating a related button on the task pane?